# Problem installing php-devel on Fedora 8 (running PHP 5.2.14)

Tags: php, yum

I'm trying to install php-devel, but getting a dependency error:

Error: Missing Dependency: php = 5.2.4-3 is needed by package php-devel

I googled around a bit but couldn't find anything too useful. Anybody seen this before? I'm sure I just need to manually yum install something but I'm not that versed with yum.

Here's the full deal:

[peter@akebono xdebug]$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.23.1-42.fc8 (kojibuilder@xenbuilder2.fedora.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20070925 (Red Hat 4.1.2-33)) #1 SMP Tue Oct 30 13:18:33 EDT 2007

[peter@akebono xdebug]$ php --version
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqli' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.2.6 (cli) (built: May  8 2008 08:54:23) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2008 Zend Technologies
    with Zend Debugger v5.2.14, Copyright (c) 1999-2008, by Zend Technologies

[peter@akebono xdebug]$ sudo yum install php-devel
Password:
Repository development is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository development-debuginfo is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository development-source is listed more than once in the configuration
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-devel.i386 0:5.2.4-3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php = 5.2.4-3 for package: php-devel
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.2.6-2.fc8 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Missing Dependency: php = 5.2.4-3 is needed by package php-devel

Comment: Looks like you already have php-devel on your system. You can confirm with yum list php-devel

Comment: this should probably be asked on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: I did yum list and yes indeed it seems to be there. However I don't seem to have "phpize", which I thought would be part of php-devel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Fedora 8 stopped being supported over a year ago, so you are almost certainly better off migrating to a newer version of Fedora (Fedora 14 at this point) or moving to RHEL if you want something that changes less frequently.